# Как в Windows менять звуковые устройства через Python

Tags: python

С помощью какого модуля python можно поменять устройство вывода звука по умолчанию в Windows 10? Не выбрать его в python, а поменять в самой операционной системе.

Comment: Насчет смены в винде - просто так это не сделать. Мелкософты не любят такие внедрения. Но можно поковыряться через изменения значений в реестре. А если нужно тупо запустить тот или иной звуковой файл через определенный аутпут, можно глянуть вот этот исходник https://github.com/bastibe/SoundCard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использовал nircmd,и вызывал через консоль

```
os.system("C:\\Users\\Antonio\\nircmd\\nircmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice \"Микрофон\"")
```